# Possible to match special characters with mod_alias and `Redirect` directive?

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, apache2

I’m using Apache 2.4.6 with `mod_alias` and have a website which is receiving traffic from a link on another website that I have no control over. The other site’s link is poorly formed and it causes visitors that come to my site from the external site to receive an immediate `400` error. The url ends in a literal `%` sign for some reason: `domain.com/news/october_news.pdf%`

*(**Side note:** Suffice it to say that the originating website cannot be contacted and will not change the URL for reasons unknown.)*

My site heavily uses `mod_alias` and the `Redirect` directive, so I was hoping to maintain consistency and use the same directive for the benefit of future webmasters. From my reading of the documentation it would seem possible, but I’ve been unable to get it to work. I’m attempting to 301 redirect anyone that goes to the URL `domain.com/news/october_news.pdf%` to `domain.com/news/october_news.pdf`. Basically I need to hack off the percentage sign. How would I go about that with `mod_alias` and `Redirect`? Or perhaps it simply cannot be done and I need to use `RedirectMatch`.

I’ve currently attempted each of the following in an `.htaccess` file:

```
redirect “/news/october_news.pdf%” “/news/october_news.pdf”
redirect “/news/october_news.pdf%25” “/news/october_news.pdf”
redirect “/news/october_news.pdf\%” “/news/october_news.pdf”
```

All of which have not changed the `400 Bad Request` error that Apache returns to the browser.

Comment: Related on SuperUser: [Why does the percent sign in a URL cause an HTTP 400 Bad Request error?](https://superuser.com/questions/759959/why-does-the-percent-sign-in-a-url-cause-an-http-400-bad-request-error) and on StackOverflow: [Apache: %25 in url (400 Bad Request)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549747/apache-25-in-url-400-bad-request)

Comment: Somebody found a way to use PHP code in the 400 error page to do redirects: https://angrychimp.net/recovering-from-apache-400-bad-request-errors/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a mod_alias `Redirect` (or even mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` - which executes *before* mod_alias) to catch a 400 "bad request". This applies to directives in both `.htaccess` and in the server config. The "bad request" is simply triggered much earlier in the request.

In fact, you can't do anything in `.htaccess` to trap the bad request. `.htaccess` is never even processed - it's too late.

However, as @Stephen suggested in comments, you can define a custom 400 error document in the *server config* and examine such requests using your server-side script (eg. PHP) to then issue an overriding redirect. But this error document *must* be defined in a *server* or *virtualhost* context; `.htaccess` (or `<Directory>` containers) is too late. For example, directly in your `<VirtualHost>` container:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /errordocs/e400.php
```

Then, in the case of PHP, you can examine the requested URL (containing the trailing `%`) using the `REDIRECT_URL` (or `REQUEST_URI`) indices of the `$_SERVER` superglobal and issue the appropriate redirect.

Make sure your default 400 response returns a reasonable / user friendly message with appropriate links, otherwise you'll likely get a browser default.

---

> ```
> redirect “/news/october_news.pdf%” “/news/october_news.pdf”
> ```

*Aside:* You should not be using curly quotes `“`..`”` to surround the arguments - the request will never match (for this reason also). If you need/want to surround the arguments then you must use straight double quotes, ie. `"`.

This is also a 302 (temporary) redirect (maybe you did this just to test?). This should ultimately be a 301 (permanent) redirect.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't thinking about the order of execution when a URL is requested from Apache. This makes sense now. Looks like I'll need to whip up a `400` app on this server for things like this. I'll server a pretty `400` for generic errors, and have special logic for known bad requests like this rogue external site with awful links. As for the curly quotes, those are artifacts my Mac inserted into my post, not actually on the server. And yes, the 302 was intentional because I got tired of having to force Chrome DevTools to ignore the 301 that it cached while testing.