# Why would googlebot be trying to crawl a URL "https://www.example.com/https://www.example.com/other/things"?

Tags: google-search-console, php, 301-redirect, googlebot, http-code-400

I've been trying to clean up crawl errors on my company's website. In one menu, google bot is trying to crawl every link with an extra-base URL attached. These pages (perhaps obviously) don't exist and return a "400 Bad Request" error.

[image: GSC screenshot showing 400 errors]

The site is built on PHP and Apache. The URL's are written dynamically by PHP, but there are also some 301 redirects associated with the pages in question.

Has anyone seen and or solved this before? Will it affect my SEO?

Comment: Are you sure Googlebot is crawling `https://www.example.com/https://www.example.com/other/things` and not `https://www.example.com/www.example.com/other/things`? The later is easy to explain, the former is not.

Comment: https://imgur.com/zSszPue

Comment: Yes is is crawling https://www.example.com/https://www.example.com/other/things. It also says it is linked from https://www.example.com/https://www.example.com/other/stuff (which seems odd since https://www.example.com/https://www.example.com/other/stuff also returns a 400 error)

Comment: That would certainly seem to be a strange one! Having had a look at your site, I can't see any problems. Maybe there _was_ a problem which is now fixed? Maybe Googlebot is seeing something different to users (although faking the user-agent doesn't reveal anything unusual)? Does the "Fetch and Render" tool in GSC show anything unusual? Your pages appear to be indexed OK - including the "correct" version of the URLs you appear to be referring to?

Comment: "In one menu" - is this a menu on your site? or in GSC?

Comment: I have cleared the errors, and they have reappeared a few days later which leads me to believe that it is still a problem. (Though problem may be a strong word since it doesn't appear to affect the users). Fetch and Render in GSC receives a 400 error on the double URL. If I remove the URL google indexes the page correctly and nothing in the HTML would point to the error. This may be one that remains a mystery. At this point, I'm mainly just curious. I've thoroughly tested that aspect of the site & don't believe the functionality is impaired.

Comment: You cannot simply clear these "errors". A 400 (error) response is arguably the correct response. You can only mark these errors as "fixed" (or _cleared_) if you made these URLs valid so they returned a 200 OK (or possibly 3xx) response. Returning a 200 OK response for these URLs would be wrong. The error reported in GSC is FYI only. However, you could consider implementing a 301 redirect instead to "correct" the URL. This is unlikely to benefit you SEO-wise, however, it could help to reduce the number of reported errors in GSC. See: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/114772/1243

Answer (score 3):

**Why is Google still indexing those links?**

It's because Google Bot found those link on your site at some point in time and that's why it indexed it. Google Bot doesn't make up URLs so it must of found it on your website. If Google indexed something once, it will come back and revisit it, even if the destination resource doesn't exists or the original link to it doesn't exist on your website anymore. My guess is that it was a programming mistake because it's easy to make that mistake, especially if your have do URLs in PHP.

**Does this affect SEO?**

Not really, links resulting in 404 errors don't affect your SEO. 
However, I would be much more concerned about the 70+ of your website ZOMBIES pages. Basically, Google crawler started indexing your website's search controller (yourwebsite.com/search). If you type into Google "site:yourwebsite.com", it will show you all indexed pages for that domain. See your Zombie pages [here](https://www.google.ie/search?q=site%3Asteelsupplylp.com%2Fsearch&oq=site%3Asteelsupplylp.com).

**How to fix it?**

- Redirect these links to throw error 410 (Gone) -  this tells Google to not revisit that URL anymore
- Mark the links as fixed in the Google Search Console

Comment: It doesn't look like the pages give 404 errors.  In the screenshot from the question, some of the pages are listed as "linked from.".   To me that indicates the site is somehow serving pages for URLs like that that then link to other pages with similar URL structure.   I'd recommend fixing that issue.